# What is the WinRT equivalent of WPF ParallelTimeline?

Tags: wpf, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'm porting some WPF code to WinRT.  The code uses System.Windows.Media.Animation.ParallelTimeline to syncrhonize two animations.  I don't see a corresponding Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.ParallelTimeline class and Ctrl + . doesn't find anything.  Does anyone know how to achieve a similar result in WinRT?

Comment: Just a blind shot - can you add the two animations to a Storyboard?

Comment: Yeah, that's the way to do it.  I had to re-work some of the other code before I could try it because it was using Storyboard.SetTargetName on some controls that were being added to the NameScope and WinRT has no NameScope concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my comment answers your question - then the answer is to add the two animations to a Storyboard.